# Dependent cell value with multiple conditions in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone could lead me in right direction here.

Basically I am looking for a formula or VBA code to change the cell A1 value depending on multiple different conditions. The conditions are different name ranges ( in form of drop down list ) in different worksheets. So for example here are the 3 different conditions:

1. If the NameRange1 in sheet1 = “yes” then cell A1 = A otherwise do nothing
2. If NameRange2 in Sheet2 = 2 Then A1 = B otherwise A1 = C
3. If none of those conditions are meet then A1 = D

I am new to Excel and I know it’s quite messy but I was thinking of nested if statements with first two conditions nested inside true statement and last condition in false?

```
=IF(A1="",IF(condition1,IF(condition2),condition3))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "If none of those conditions are meet then A1 = D" - seems like that's already covered in (2), with the result being "C" ?

Comment: How can you get by the first rule.  A1 is either A or do nothing, nothing would preclude A1 from being anything else.

Comment: Ok let’s put it differently. The value in A1 depends from the option I choose from drop dawn list. Let’s say I need:  A1 = A if  answered “yes” otherwise D if answered “No” OR A1 = B if answered “red” otherwise A1 = C if answered “black” These would be my dependent conditions. How could you put it into excel formula ?.

Comment: `IF(range1 = "yes", "A", IF(range1="no", "D", ""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, looks like this will work:

```
=IF(nameRange1="yes","A",IF(nameRange2="red","B",IF(nameRange2="black","C","D")))
```

If that is not exactly what you need, you can at least see the IF embedding pattern and adjust for your needs.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I have extended this with few more conditions but kept the the principle. Thanks for that